# WebApi Controller Get Action Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having trouble with one of my WebApi2 controllers. While writing tests I've discovered the Get() is never hit instead it returns a 301 followed by 403. Oddly if I hit Get(id) the second action speaks up and does its job, but I can never hit the Get() action. If I rename the controller it works properly, but sadly, I cannot rename ModelsController to ModelController as I would like since there is an existing user base expecting that name. This is a rewrite of an existing Api that was done in MVC2 I think. All the other controllers work great, just not this one.

Any thoughts as to how to debug this?  Or what I may have missed?

Other notes:
The routing configuration is default.
There is no other ModelsController to be found

Below is a simplified version of my code, and the problem remains...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using TW.Api.Business.Services.Models;

namespace TW.Api.Business.Services.Controllers
{
    public class ModelsController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public string Get(string id)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace tw.api.business
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Api_GetWithChild",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{childId}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Get", childId = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "Api_Post",
              routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{childId}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Post", childId = RouteParameter.Optional },
              constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api_Put",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}/{action}/{childId}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "Put", childId = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("PUT") });

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
            // To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
            // For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
            //config.EnableQuerySupport();

            // To disable tracing in your application, please comment out or remove the following line of code
            // For more information, refer to: http://www.asp.net/web-api
            //config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace tw.api.business
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your route configuration, and if you have anything else this is very simple and should just work. I'm wondering if you have some other route that eagerly handles this url in the larger app?

An easy workaround for name conflicts is to use attribute routing

Comment: as I noted the route setup is what comes out of the box...  but here it is...  I had thought about trying attribute routing, but it burns me to no end that it insn't already working...  That said, I may have to...  On second thought... I think I lied, it doesn't look very out of the box.  Thanks...

Comment: Yeah the constrained routes are not necessary at all. The default out of the box route should get you where you need to go.

Comment: ok, I went to the default and still had the problem...

Comment: I tried attribute routing, I did several different things including setting route order.  No Luck, then next I created a whole new WebApi using the Project Template as usual...  Then I created a controller called ModelsController.  Next I adjusted the default routeTemplate as I usually do...

routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", to   routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",

problem now recreates in the out of box webapi as well... So it is MVC doing this... Usually I remove MVC completely, but this time I left it in for the HelpPages...  Anyone have a thought as to how to get around it?

Comment: one other note.. I also tried adjusting the routeconfig for mvc from  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  to  url: "web/{controller}/{action}/{id}",  with no joy... atleast I now know the cause.. :)

Comment: you don't need the default MVC routes for help pages, help pages are an area.

and the route: {controller}/{id}/{action}/{childId} is not necessary, because Get is recognized as a verb. so {controller}/{id}/{childId} works just fine (assuming id and child id are optional)

Comment: right, I didn't note I also tried commenting the routeconfig out completely... and the reference to registerroutes in global.asax...

Comment: I did however, keep the WebApiConfig routing. :)

Comment: Like a mention below, start by simplifying out your route configuration. Then my guess is that something else is responding to the Models controller Get.

If you can share a very simplified repro of your app, I'll gladly take a look for you

Comment: I was given authorization to change the name as I wanted to all along so the issue is sort of closed.... that said, I have added it to GitHub  https://github.com/lendog75/WebApiModelsIssue

Thanks :)

GET /models/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54692
Content-Type: application/json

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your route config, there are a few issues

1. The constrained routes are not really necessary
2. The id being optional in a middle of a route pattern doesn't really work, your optional items should come at the end.

Answer (score 1):

When creating methods for web-API end-points, you **must follow some naming conventions** for automatically mapping of method-to-api. Or you can override that using HTTP action and Route attributes

Follow either of the following arrangements (note the 'Model' and 'Models' in method names):

```
public class ModelsController : ApiController
{
    public string GetModels()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string GetModel(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Or, use the route attributes:

```
public class ModelsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Models")]
    public string GetModels()
    {
        return null;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Models/{id}")]
    public string GetModel(string id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Ref: [Routing and Action Selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)